# Why my Java class methods are not being called from the native code? JNI, NDK/SDK

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, user-permissions

I am developing an app NDK/SDK in Android Studio and want the Android while running my app to show the menu of the write permissions so the user can activate it. But my Java class methods(MainActivity.java) are not being called from the native code(android_main.cpp ).

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

android_main.cpp:

```
    void callJavaRequestPermissions(struct android_app* app) {
    JNIEnv* env = nullptr;
    app->activity->vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, nullptr);

    jclass activityClass = env->GetObjectClass(app->activity->clazz);

    if (activityClass != nullptr) {
        jmethodID customRequestMethod = env->GetMethodID(activityClass, "customRequestPermissions",                                                    "([Ljava/lang/String;I)V");

        if (customRequestMethod != nullptr) {
            jobjectArray permissions = env->NewObjectArray(1, env->FindClass("java/lang/String"), nullptr);
            jstring permission = env->NewStringUTF("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
            env->SetObjectArrayElement(permissions, 0, permission);

            env->CallVoidMethod(app->activity->clazz, customRequestMethod, permissions, 1);

            env->DeleteLocalRef(permission);
            env->DeleteLocalRef(permissions);
        } else {
            // Handle the case when customRequestMethod is NULL
        }
    } else {
        // Handle the case when activityClass is NULL
    }

    app->activity->vm->DetachCurrentThread();
}


void android_main(struct android_app* app) {
    char name[ PATH ], str[ PATH ];
    FILE *fp;
    unsigned int size;

    // JNI acts as a bridge between the Java and native code.
    callJavaRequestPermissions(app);
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.google.sample.simcode;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.NativeActivity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

public class MainActivity extends NativeActivity {

private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public void customRequestPermissions(String[] permissions, int requestCode) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, requestCode);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    // Handle the permission request result if needed
}
}
```

I call the callJavaRequestPermissions(app) just one time at the start of the app, before any native code, and double-checked for Classpath and Package Names, without debugging and logs, but after running jmethodID customRequestMethod = env->GetMethodID(activityClass, "customRequestPermissions", "([Ljava/lang/String;I)V"); I have   customRequestMethod = NULL

Comment: This is a common gotcha: [FindClass does not work outside the main thread](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#faq:-why-didnt-findclass-find-my-class). Also, `requestPermissions` is empty so what is the point of calling it? Please reduce your code to an [mre] that exhibits the problem

Comment: thank you the first problem was solved and I have changed my source. At the moment customRequestMethod is NULL

Comment: Turn on verbose JNI checks, check if there is a JNI error registered, check if `app->activity->clazz` is not null.

Comment: No, it is not NULL. activityClass=0x0000000000000005, clazz in app->activity->clazz=0x0000000000002692

Comment: Can you verify that the `app->activity->clazz` object is actually an instance of your `MainActivity`? You can use `IsAssignableFrom` or call some methods on the Class object.

Comment: jclass activityClass = env->GetObjectClass(app->activity->clazz);

    if (activityClass != nullptr) {
        jclass mainActivityClass = env->GetObjectClass(app->activity->clazz);
        if (env->IsSameObject(activityClass, mainActivityClass)) {
            jmethodID customRequestMethod = env->GetMethodID(activityClass, "customRequestPermissions",
                                                             "([Ljava/lang/String;I)V");
   }
  }
activityClass and mainActivityClass are not NULL

Comment: What is that supposed to prove? You just ran the same expression twice. Compare the output of `GetObjectClass` with the output of `FindClass(".../MainActivity")`, rather.

Comment: FindClass return NULL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254954/discussion-between---and-botje).

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved. with replacing customRequestPermissions to the requestPermissions

Comment: That is only a "solution" because you're calling to the method present in nativeactivity. The proper solution is to figure out why your class is not being instantiated.